# Firestore: get an Observable doc from another field which is not the Id

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I want to get a single Observable from a collection, but I want to get it from a different field that is not the id. It is possible?

I do not want to do a query and limit to 1. I need to get a Single Observable not an array Observable.

Schema:

[image: Schema]

Code:

```
this.afs.doc<Credit>('credits/uid/'+ uid).valueChanges();
```

Error:

> Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but credits/uid/d1Zt8sozYqb6H27lhoJgF1Gx2Cc2 has 3

Comment: There is something wrong with the schema you have provided.  The documents contains only fields...Or is this first field `id` a document ID and which contain two fields?

Comment: @vitooh I have include a picture of the schema.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand correctly, but I guess that you want to get document with particular `uid` field value, not using document id.

This particular error is related with common feature of Firestore, that every document has to be in collection not in document. So `path` values for documents, (nested as well) are always checked, if  the segments (devided by `/`) number is even ex. `collection1/doc1/collection2/doc2/collection3/doc3`

As results in your code we have 3 segments (like `credits/uid/<uid_value>`) so this is the error.

I am not very familiar with angularFire2 itself, but I have done it in JS. The approach is normally to query collection and than use method on the results, which in classic JS returns `Query` object on which the same methods can be used as on `CollectionReference` (which extends 'Query' btw - [reference 1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#where)).

Combining this approach with those references: [querying](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md) and [collection](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md) I propose following solution:

```
this.afs.collection('credits', ref => ref.where('uid', '==', <uid_value>)).valueChanges()
```

If `uid_value` will be unique you should get your doc.

Unfortunately I do not have any playground to test the solution so please let me know how it works - or if there will be any additional errors.

I hope it will help! Good Luck!

Comment: This way you get an Observable<Credit[]> Not an Observable<Credit>. I want to get a single object not an array of Credit